# Django Migration using a OneToOneField

Tags: django, migration

Migration for a OneToOneField returns an error as follows :

MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'auth_user'")

My models are as follows :

```
    class Employer(models.Model):
        emp_Name = models.OneToOneField(User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        emp_Company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        emp_Address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        emp_Tel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        emp_JobTitle = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        emp_JobDesc = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=False)
        def __str__(self):
           return self.emp_Name

    class CVmaker(models.Model):
        cv_User = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        cv_Title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        cv_Basic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        cv_Timeline = models.ForeignKey('Journeyeval', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        cv_ComAddress = models.CharField(max_length=400)
        cv_Edu = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        cv_Test = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        cv_Mmedia = models.ImageField(upload_to='candidates_pics/')
        cv_Referrals = models.CharField(max_length=400)
        cv_Templates = models.CharField(max_length=400)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.cv_Title
```

I have two database routers one for the [auth, session, admin and contenttypes] and the other for the main app.
It works for ForeignKey.
I am creating a job portal and require the employer to be able to login too.

The routers are as follows :

```
    class AuthRouter:

        route_app_labels = ('auth', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 
        'admin')

        def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

            if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
                return "default"
            return False

        def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

            if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
                return "default" 
            return False

        def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
            if (obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
                obj2._meta.app_label == 'redford'
                ):
                return True
            return None

        def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, 
        **hints):

            if db == 'default':

                if app_label in 
                     ('auth','admin','sessions','contenttypes'):
                     return True            

                else:
                    return False
            elif app_label in ['auth','admin','sessions','contenttypes']:
                return False
    # Otherwise no opinion, defer to other routers or default database
            return None
```

There are two db's 'default' for the auth type and 'redford_db' for employer class
The routers work with 'ForeignKey' only have this problem with 'OneToOneKey'.
Also when on the error, I migrate the database again, it works without an error giving me the thought that the tables have been created all fine.

Comment: Since it is in another database, it can not introduce a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. So your router should specify that. Can you please share relevant details of the router?

Comment: I thought this was regular

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem - put up the dbRouter for the auth class.  I wonder if you are thinking that the application references the auth database with the main app name.